# 40-50s Bollywood movie about a family breaking

Tags: identify-this-movie

I watched this family drama movie in 1998-1999. And I want to watch it again.

**Possible Release year**

I watched it in 1998-99 on TV. Since it was a black and white movie, I guess it might have released around 1945-1960.

**Genre, language and country**

It was Hindi Bollywood family drama movie.

**Plots I remember**

In this movie, a lady, possibly the lead actress, marries a man who is widowed and has a child from his first marriage. He got some brothers, perhaps two or three.

After a while, he lets her sister live at his home, who was also widowed. Everybody was happy and praises that lady.

One of his brother marries a girl. After that, a fight starts among them. Because of this, one of his brothers leaves his studies and join the army.

Another brother settles in a big city, perhaps Mumbai. And the lead actor lives in a small house at his village.

The whole movie revolves around this story.

Does it ring bell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The B&W drama [Bhabhi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhabhi_(1957_film)) from 1957 seems to have the exact same plot.

> Although a graduate in Arts, **Shanta agrees to get married to a much lesser educated widowed businessman, Ratanlal, who has a son, Mithu, from his first marriage, and re-locates to live with him, his brothers; Ramesh, Rajan, & Baldev, and an aunt. Ratanlal permits her to let her child-widowed sister, Lata, to also live with them. Shanta soon earns the respect and love of everyone in the family. Ramesh gets married to Advocate Motilal's daughter, Tara, while Rajan gets married to Mangala, who is Munshiram's daughter. After these marriages, misunderstandings crop up**, generally generated by Mangala, so much so that Tara joins forces with her, **forcing the brothers to separate from each other**, with Ratanlal dividing the property and business equally amongst them, and re-locating in a small village house, while Ramesh now lives with Tara and her brother, Jeevan and his wife. **Rajan does not get along with Mangala, takes to alcohol in a big way, stops his medical studies and joins the army**, and Baldev re-locates to Bombay. The question remains will this troubled family ever be re-united again during their respective lifetimes?

It was a remake of [Kula Dheivam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kula_Dheivam) from 1956 (which was apparently *itself* a remake of the Bengali film *Banga Kora*) and later remade as [Jenu Goodu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenu_Goodu) in 1963. The movie is currently available on Youtube. Here are the first 14 minutes:

Comment: Wonderful. It is the one.